# Jquery Button click event not working

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, hybrid

I am building a small Hybrid mobile app for my android device, I am using with jquerymobile, jquery, Ajax, PHP, MySQL, etc. I am new to hybrid apps. I have wrapped the app in cordova and installed on my device. The login button does seems to only refresh the page but doesn't fire the jquery event when clicked or touched. It doesn't even do the form validation. However, this works perfectly in a browser (I have uploaded same html file on a remote server).

```
<script>
     $(document).on('click', '#btnLogin', function(e)                        
    {   
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();                 


        FORM VALIDATION COMES HERE

        AJAX COMES HERE
        $.ajax(....);


    });
```

```
<!--*************************************HOME PAGE BELOW**********************************-->

    <div data-role="page" id="home"> <!-------------- Home page starts here ----------->

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="ui_mobile">

            <h1>Grade-App 2018</h1>
        </div>


        <div role="main" class="ui-content">

            <h1>Welcome to Grade-App!</h1>

            <p> <b> Check Your Exam Results</b> </p>

            <p> Existing Users</p>
            <a href="#login_Page" id="login_link" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all" data-transition="slide" data-ajax="false" data-prefetch="true" > Click to Sign-In</a>

        </div>


        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="ui_mobile">
            <h1>© 2018 Grade-App | All Rights Reserved</h1>
        </div>
    </div> <!-------------- Home page ends here ----------->


    <!--*************************************login PAGE BELOW**********************************-->

    <div data-role="page" id="login_Page"> <!-------------- Login page  ----------->

         <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="ui_mobile">
            <a href="#home" data-icon="home" data-ajax="false" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-prefetch="true">Home</a>
            <h1>Grade-App 2018</h1>
        </div>



        <div id="login_div" data-role="content" class="ui-content" data-theme="e"> <!-- Login content Div-->


            <br><br>
            <p style="color:#CC191C;">Student and Admin Staff Login</p>
            <br><br>

            <hr> <!--<br><br>-->

            <form  method="post" action="" data-ajax="false" data-transition="pop" data-direction="reverse" id="login_form" >       


                <!--<p id="errorMsg" class="error" style="color:#ED0E11"> </p>--> <!--This is to display validation message-->  

                <div class="err" id="error"></div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">

                    <!--<label for="username" id="lblusername" name="lblusername"> User Name <span style="color:#ED0F13"> *</span>:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="User Name" title="Please enter User Name" />-->

                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="User Name" title="Please enter User Name"  />

                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">

                    <!--<label for="password" id="lblPassword" name="lblPassword"> Password <span style="color:#ED0F13"> *</span>:</label>-->
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" title="Please enter Password" />

                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">

                    <label for="chck_rememberme">Remember me</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chck_rememberme" id="chck_rememberme" checked="">                      

                </div>

                <hr>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">

                <input type="submit" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" data-inline="false" value="Sign-In" id="btnLogin" name="btnLogin" role="button" class="ui-btn" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="top" data-theme="e" />


               <!-- <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Login" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn" role="button" />-->

               </div>

            </form>     

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="ui_mobile"><h1>© 2018 Grade-App | All Rights Reserved</h1></div>     

        </div> <!-- End of Login Content Div-->



     </div> <!-- End of Login page-->
```

I have multiple pages in one HTML file and using Internal page links. As I said, the code works fine in browsers. The Hybrid version is not firing the code in this:  $(document).on('click', '#btnLogin', function(e){ .... }

Do you have any idea why it is not working in cordova? I don't know if I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!--*************************************HOME PAGE BELOW**********************************-->

        <div data-role="page" id="home"> <!-------------- Home page starts here ----------->

            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="ui_mobile">

                <h1>Grade-App 2018</h1>
            </div>


            <div role="main" class="ui-content">

                <h1>Welcome to Grade-App!</h1>

                <p> <b> Check Your Exam Results</b> </p>

                <p> Existing Users</p>
                <a href="#login_Page" id="login_link" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all" data-transition="slide" data-ajax="false" data-prefetch="true" > Click to Sign-In</a>

            </div>


            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="ui_mobile">
                <h1>© 2018 Grade-App | All Rights Reserved</h1>
            </div>
        </div> <!-------------- Home page ends here ----------->


        <!--*************************************login PAGE BELOW**********************************-->

        <div data-role="page" id="login_Page"> <!-------------- Login page  ----------->

             <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="ui_mobile">
                <a href="#home" data-icon="home" data-ajax="false" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-prefetch="true">Home</a>
                <h1>Grade-App 2018</h1>
            </div>



            <div id="login_div" data-role="content" class="ui-content" data-theme="e"> <!-- Login content Div-->


                <br><br>
                <p style="color:#CC191C;">Student and Admin Staff Login</p>
                <br><br>

                <hr> <!--<br><br>-->

                <form  method="post" action="" data-ajax="false" data-transition="pop" data-direction="reverse" id="login_form" >       


                    <!--<p id="errorMsg" class="error" style="color:#ED0E11"> </p>--> <!--This is to display validation message-->  

                    <div class="err" id="error"></div>

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">

                        <!--<label for="username" id="lblusername" name="lblusername"> User Name <span style="color:#ED0F13"> *</span>:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="User Name" title="Please enter User Name" />-->

                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="User Name" title="Please enter User Name"  />

                    </div>

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">

                        <!--<label for="password" id="lblPassword" name="lblPassword"> Password <span style="color:#ED0F13"> *</span>:</label>-->
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" title="Please enter Password" />

                    </div>

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">

                        <label for="chck_rememberme">Remember me</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="chck_rememberme" id="chck_rememberme" checked="">                      

                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">

                    <input type="submit" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" data-inline="false" value="Sign-In" id="btnLogin" name="btnLogin" role="button" class="ui-btn" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="top" data-theme="e" />


                   <!-- <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Login" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn" role="button" />-->

                   </div>

                </form>     

                <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="ui_mobile"><h1>© 2018 Grade-App | All Rights Reserved</h1></div>     

            </div> <!-- End of Login Content Div-->
```

## Below script check

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnLogin").click(function(e){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();                 
            alert('enter');
        });
        });

        </script>
```

Comment: Please add this script :- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: I did try but no joy.

Comment: Hi sunny, as I indicated in my first post, it works perfectly fine on the server. I am trying to do two things: 1. a normal browser web app 2. Hybrid app (this is installed directly onto a mobile device) with cordova. The normal web app is working perfectly. I am having issues with the hybrid app.